# Play sound while swiping images

Tags: android

I am making an android app on which user swipes through different images. I want to play a different sound on each image swipes accordingly. This is my code looks like

```
package com.horizontalscrollviewwithpageindicator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class PageIndicatorActivity extends Activity {

private static final Object S1 = null;
private static final Object S2 = null;
private static final Object S3 = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

public class OurSoundPlayer{
public static final int S1 = R.raw.ss;
public static final int S2 = R.raw.uu;
public static final int S3 = R.raw.rr;
}

private static SoundPool soundPool;
private static HashMap soundPoolMap;

public static void initSounds(Context context) {
soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
soundPoolMap = new HashMap(3);     
soundPoolMap.put( S1, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.ss, 1) );
soundPoolMap.put( S2, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.uu, 2) );
soundPoolMap.put( S3, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.rr, 3) );
}

public static void playSound(Context context, int soundID) {
if(soundPool == null || soundPoolMap == null){
initSounds(context);
}
float volume = (float) 1.0;
soundPool.play((Integer) soundPoolMap.get(soundID), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
private int imageArra[] = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f,

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
return true;
}
}
```

Now here i want to play different sounds according to the image which are in the array.

Comment: you can add listener to the viewpage onPageChanged and play the sound

Comment: actually i am new for android. I don't have excess knowledge of this I just started to build can you tell me how it is to be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swipe Images with little sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014928/swipe-images-with-little-sound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should give you an idea on how to play a sound everytime your switch to the next View

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pageId) {
            //TODO you will have to add some logic here that matches the
            // the pages id to the soundId
            playSound(this, pageId); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

public static void playSound(Context context, int soundID) {
    if(soundPool == null || soundPoolMap == null){
        initSounds(context);
    }
    float volume = (float) 1.0;
    soundPool.play((Integer) soundPoolMap.get(soundID), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

i haven't tried this, but this should work. Or at least give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: you have to implement the onPageChnageListener according to you needs. i dont know what exactly it is you want to do. but playing a sound on new pahe selectio would definetly work like this

Comment: I have done this. but the sound is not getting synchronized with image. I used this code for sound.    if (mp != null) {mp.reset();
               mp.release();
               }
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this,mAudio[position]);
     mp.start();
     return imageView;

Comment: you havent implemented a pageChangeListener. At least not in the class you showed me.

Comment: i am not getting perfect clue for this. If u can help me according to my this code (http://brightcm.com/numbers.html) then it will be helpful for me. Please its request..

Comment: Please help me according to my code because i found lot of solutions & none is working So now i am getting confused.

Comment: i implemented what i think i necessary to work. basically evertime a new page is selected a sound will be played once you matched the pageIds to their sound counterparts. Should be an easy job, if you know which sound you want to play

Comment: can i see how you implemented it?

Comment: i posted it here, just check it.

Comment: see this i made it according you told me & posted here but it not playing any sound. I posted this. please have a look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108842/sound-not-playing-on-image-swipe-in-veiwpager/21108972?noredirect=1#comment31759764_21108972)

Comment: ok, code seems fine, but after reading Andros wrote im pretty sure you learnn how to handle the basics if you cant log the onselected event.

Comment: you can figure it out with logging.

Comment: I have done this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161165/all-sound-not-loaded-in-array) & it works me but still see the problem i got from this..